# Segmentation fault clang

Tags: c, cs50

[what I try to do](http://cdn.cs50.net/2016/fall/walkthroughs/caesar/c/caesar.pdf)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
    if (isalpha(atoi(argv[i]))) {
      printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  int k = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (argc == 2) {
    string pt = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    char ct[strlen(pt)];
    for (int i = 0; i < (strlen(pt)); i++) {
      if (isalpha(pt[i]) && isupper(pt[i])) {
        ct[i] = ((pt[i] - 65) + k) % 26;
        printf("%c", ct[i] + 65);
      } else if (isalpha(pt[i]) && islower(pt[i])) {
        ct[i] = ((pt[i] - 97) + k) % 26;
        printf("%c", ct[i] + 97);
      }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  else if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar keyn\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

if I pass 20x it must show me (Usage: ./caesar)
instead of that I get Segmentation fault why!!
can anyone help me and I will be thanx

Comment: You are indexing `argv` out of bounds.

Comment: It would be helpful for you if you also try to learn tools like https://valgrind.org/

Comment: This code `isalpha(atoi(argv[i]))` is just really confused, what are you actually trying to do here? It look like you are trying to check if all the characters of `argv[1]` are digits. The correct code for that would be `!isdigit(argv[1][i])` because you want to print the error message if the *ith* character of argv[1] is not a digit.

Answer (score 3):

Your first loop iterates through the number of characters in the first command argument, and tries to access the command argument of that index. So if you have only one command argument, but that argument has more than 2 characters then you will be trying to access an element in `argv` beyond the end of the array.

Comment: ok I fix it but there is another bug when I didn't pass anything it must show Usage: ./caesar but I get seg. error

Comment: @FuratMostafaSmadi you have `int k = atoi(argv[1]);` before you check how many arguments you actually have.